# Why does Maven's dependency mediation not choose the newest version?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

If a Maven project transitively uses multiple versions of a library, Maven's dependency mediation will arbitrate by nearest definition and order in the declaration. (See the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).)

E.g. if A -> B -> X-1.0.0 and A -> B -> C -> X-2.0.0, then building A will use X-1.0.0.

Why? It is reasonable to assume that X-2.0.0 has added some method that is used by C, so running A will probably produce a runtime exception. Wouldn't it make more sense to choose the newest version? (I know you could specify it manually.)

Answer (score 1):

It is also reasonable to assume that a 2.x version has *removed* some method that is used by A or B.  Maven can't know which is correct in this case and decides that the nearest definition is the tiebreaker.  If the developer doesn't like this choice s/he can add a direct dependency, as you observed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any good reason to do this. It seems to cause more trouble than it saves.

Ivy's default dependency mediation strategy is "newest", not "nearest", and it seems to work very well in almost all cases. See http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/settings/conflict-managers.html